# NoReverseMatch error in Django [Pinax]

Tags: django, django-views

My Django project based on pinax-social fails loading any page which has `{% url home %}` in it, and shows this:

```
NoReverseMatch at /account/login/
Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Hardcoding the url fixes the problem, and only the home ReverseMatch fails.

Here's my urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from .views import *
from NEOreka.models import *
from .forms import SignupForm
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns("neo.views",
    url(r"^neo/(?P<neo_id>\d+)/$", "neo_info"),
)

urlpatterns += patterns("",
    url(r"^$", "neo.views.home"),
)
urlpatterns += patterns("", 
    url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r"^account/signup/$", SignupView.as_view(), name="account_signup"),
    url(r"^account/", include("account.urls")),
    )
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Could someone tell me how I could fix this?

Comment: What version of django are you using? If its 1.5, then [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/releases/1.3/#changes-to-url-and-ssi) might be of interest. Basically, you need to add quotes before your url argument ie `{% url 'home' %}`

Comment: Erm, no, I'm on 1.4.3 as that's what Pinax auto-installs in virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I test this one and it works. I hope it will works also in your side.

```
 {% url neo.views.home %}
```